# DevDemon Updater not reading config overrides

Tags: devdemon, devdemon-updater

Updater doesn't seem to be reading the [Configuration File overrides](http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/updater/#config-overrides-updater) that I'm setting in `config.php`.

Here's part of my config.php:

```
// $base_path and other variables defined above this
$config['updater_module_defaults']['path_map']['root'] = $base_path . '/';
$config['updater_module_defaults']['path_map']['backup'] = $base_path . '/updater_backup/';
$config['updater_module_defaults']['path_map']['system'] = $base_path . '/' . $system_folder . '/';
$config['updater_module_defaults']['path_map']['system_third_party'] = $config['third_party_path'];
$config['updater_module_defaults']['path_map']['themes'] = $config['theme_folder_path'];
$config['updater_module_defaults']['path_map']['themes_third_party'] = $config['theme_folder_path'] . 'third_party/';
```

And the Settings don't change as I update this file, nor are the input fields disabled. Updater appears to only use the settings in the database.

I'm using Updater 3.2.17 on EE 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
// $base_path and other variables defined above this
$config['updater']['path_map']['root'] = $base_path . '/';
$config['updater']['path_map']['backup'] = $base_path . '/updater_backup/';
$config['updater']['path_map']['system'] = $base_path . '/' . $system_folder . '/';
$config['updater']['path_map']['system_third_party'] = $config['third_party_path'];
$config['updater']['path_map']['themes'] = $config['theme_folder_path'];
$config['updater']['path_map']['themes_third_party'] = $config['theme_folder_path'] . 'third_party/';
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Can you update the docs?